# Handling Very Large volume(500TB) data using spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have large volume of data nearly 500TB , I have to do some ETL on that data.

This data is there in the AWS S3, so I planning to use AWS EMR setup to process this data but I am not sure what should be the config I should select .

1. What kind of cluster I need(master and how many slaves)?
2. Do I need to process chunk by chunk(10GB) or can I process all data at once?
3. What should be Master and slave(executor) memory both Ram and storage?
4. What kind of processor (speed) I need?

Based on this I want to calculate the cost of AWS EMR and start process the data

Comment: Nobody can not possibly answer this question. What is the data ? What is the processing ? You'll have very different answers if your data is DNA samples and your computation is "find all permutations exprressing gene X", or if your data is log files and the computation is count the ERROR logs. And even if we know this and that... only vaguely accurate guess would be : try the first 100GB and if it is doable, the first TB, and then scale.

Comment: The question is too broad and the answers also will be based on assumptions.

Comment: If you have 500TB in AWS, you should have a good relationship with one of their SAs.  If not, open up a support ticket with more specific details.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your question, you have little or no experience with Hadoop. Get some training first so that you understand how the Hadoop ecosystem works. Plan on spending three months to get to a starter level.

You have a lot of choices to make, some are fundamental to a project's success. For example, what language (Scala, Java or Python)? Which tools (Spark, Hive, Pig, etc.). What format is your data in (CSV, XML, JSON, Parquet, etc.).  Do you only need batch processing or do you require near real-time analysis, etc. etc. etc.

You may find other AWS services more applicable such as Athena or Redshift depending on what format your data is in and what information you are trying to extract / process.

With 500 TB in AWS, open a ticket with support. Explain what you have, what you want and your time frame. An SA will be available to direct you on a path.

Comment: My data is json data, and as many suggested I want to go with spark+yarn, so I am confused what kind of cluster I need. Due to some limitation I can not ask SA

Comment: Reread my answer. You need to provide all of the information that I asked about to an SA for him to help you. Spark+YARN is just Spark installed on Hadoop which is a normal configuration option. A mistake in your design processing 500 TB could cost you $45,000 in data transfer fees if you don't know what you are doing ($.09 per GB). Speak to an Hadoop and AWS expert before you continue.